# AppScript - possible customization of authorization notifications?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

AppScript notification  message is as follows:

"You are getting this email because you have accessed and granted permission to Tool.

What is Tool?
Tool is a third party application written using Google Apps Script. This application is not affiliated with Google.com. It was developed by developer@domain.com. If you need any support or help with respect to this application then please contact developer@domain.com, who is the owner of this application.

How can I uninstall Tool?
You can click the button below to uninstall Tool.
Uninstall Tool

About Google Apps Script
Tool is built using Google Apps Script. All applications developed using Google Apps Script are served from script.google.com. Google makes no guarantee about the security of any application developed by a third party.Please click here to learn more about Google Apps Script.
Please click here to Report Abuse.

©2013 Google Inc., 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA. Terms of Service | Privacy Policy
"

It is pretty obvious that the author (or rather last modifier) of the script (developer@domain.com) can be changed to some technical account created solely for the purpose of maintaing the app script code. 
Customer questions are following:

1. Can sender email address be from own domain (@domain.com)?
2. Can the actual contents of message be customized/modified - end users see them cryptic and potentially spammy?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions is currently no, although you can file feature requests on the issue tracker.